Pgfplot multiline text inside pin label
Is it the case that pgfplot do not allow for multiline text? I tried text\\text but got an error message. Checked possibly relative questions but did not come accross an example.
\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ytick align=outside,
            ticks=none,
            samples=1000,
            xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi,
            ymin=-1,ymax=4
            ]

\addplot[domain={-4*pi:4*pi},]
{1.5*sin(deg(x/2-pi))+2};

\addplot[domain={-4*pi:4*pi},dashed]
{2};

\node [coordinate,pin=-360:{D: vertical\\ shift}] at (axis cs:2*pi,1)   {};
\draw[orange, thin] (2*pi,2)--(2*pi,0);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}



add align=center (or left etc.) to this nodes options. See the manual // the blank before shift will be ignored anyway by align

This question is similar to: Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes. (pins are just another node) If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is unrelated to PGFPlots - the pin, (node and label) works exactly the same as in TikZ without PGFPlots.

The duplicate mentioned here doesn't apply, as it doesn't mention the syntax required for the pin-related part \node[coordinate, pin={[align=center]right:{D: vertical\\shift}}] at (2*pi,1) {}; , see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730920/245790

Here are two ways to do it, and there may be more.

The problem is that pin is intended to place an extra node, which unfortunately has no further text-options (in Tikz) to process. Also style options (pgfplots) don't seem to always work. So you can mimick this behavior one way or the other.
1) pin styles (black) ... also clipped by axes:
        % ~~~ limited effects ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        every pin/.style={color=teal,align=left,anchor=south west},
    ]
...
    % pin-text has no further options, so this can't work
    \node [coordinate,pin=45:{D: vertical\\ shift}] at (axis cs:2*pi,1.5)   {};

2) node inside axes ... brown
    % ~~~ alternatives ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [align=right,anchor=west,brown] % add xshift, if needed
           at (axis cs:2*pi,1) {D: vertical\\shift};

3) Reusing (X) after axes ... magenta + blue

drawing from (X) to the right
putting a new node
doing some anchor and shift magic

   \end{axis}
   
    % ~~~ outside axies ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[magenta] (X) -- 
                    node[align=right,
                         anchor=west,
                         blue,
                         xshift=4mm
                        ] {D: vertical\\shift} 
                    +(0.6,0) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}     


\documentclass[border=1pc]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}   % not needed here
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1]
   \begin{axis}[
        %width=\textwidth,  % meaningless in standalone
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ytick align=outside,
        ticks=none,
        samples=1000,
        xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi,
        ymin=-1,ymax=4,
        % ~~~ limited effects ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        every pin/.style={color=teal,align=left,anchor=south west},
    ]

    \addplot[domain={-4*pi:4*pi},] {1.5*sin(deg(x/2-pi))+2};
    \addplot[domain={-4*pi:4*pi},dashed] {2};

    % pin-text has no further options, so this can't work
    \node [coordinate,pin=45:{D: vertical\\ shift}] at (axis cs:2*pi,1.5)   {};

    % ~~~ alternatives ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [align=right,anchor=west,brown] % add xshift, if needed
           at (axis cs:2*pi,1) {D: vertical\\shift};
    
    % ~~~ node (X) will be remembered below ~~~
    \draw[orange, thin] (2*pi,2) -- 
                node[pos=.85](X){} (2*pi,0);    
   \end{axis}
   
    % ~~~ outside axies ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[magenta] (X) -- 
                    node[align=right,
                         anchor=west,
                         blue,
                         xshift=4mm
                        ] {D: vertical\\shift} 
                    +(0.6,0) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}

This part can well be absorbed by a \newcommand\mypin ...

A pin is just an extra node (like a label) and has all the same options - the options are given like the label.

What do you mean by "style options (pgfplots) don't seem to always work"? Do you have an example?

See every pin in code above. // Is your solution documented in the manual?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
axis lines=center,
ticks=none,
xmin=-4*pi, xmax=4*pi,
ymin=-1, ymax=4
]
\addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi, samples=100, smooth] {1.5*sin(deg(x/2-pi))+2};
\addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi, samples=2, dashed] {2};
\node[coordinate, pin={[align=center]right:{D: vertical\\shift}}] at (2*pi,1) {};
\draw[orange, thin] (2*pi,2) -- (2*pi,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}


